# Why doesn't Crystal Server pick up a user's (new) active directory groups?

Tags: crystal-reports, active-directory

We are running Crystal Reports Server 11.5. We have set it up for AD authentication and I have mapped the correct groups under Authentication in the CMC.

The issue we are having is that when a user is added to a group in AD, Crystal Server does not pick up this change.

The really weird thing is that if you go to CMC and view the Group's members then the newly added user is displayed in the list (from the group point of view they are in the group), but when you go to the User's groups the group they have been added too is not listed (from a user's point of view they are not in the group).

The user does not receive the permissions they should when they login.

I have found a work around that when restarting the Central Management Server windows service Crystal seems to do resynchronization with AD.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Is this a known issue?